# How to publish a plain html web site on GitLab Pages without CI's, runner's, etc?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages

I want to use GitLab Pages service, but I am unable/not willing to provide my card to enable GitLab CI, which is now restricted. How can I publish a plain html website without using any of this processing bs? Plain html does not need any processing!

Comment: Is the project public?

Comment: Yes, public, open source

Answer (score -1):

I've searched alternatives to Gitlab.com providing Gitlab Pages, and I'm now using the [french non-profit Framasoft](https://roneo.org/en/hugo-host-for-free-on-frama.io)

The flow is simple and no CB is required (it's a non-profit living from donations): to enable HTML rendering, at the root of your repo, add a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` containing the following lines:

```
pages:
 script:
 - mkdir .public
 - cp -r * .public
 - mv .public public
 artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

Your file should then be available at `https://username.frama.io/project-name/filename.html`

See this post for details: [Free hosting for Hugo on frama.io](https://roneo.org/en/hugo-host-for-free-on-frama.io)

BTW, I've verified and the Gitlab.com CI is still free for basic usage:

> Free features:
>
> - 5GB storage [1](https://roneo.org/en/hugo-host-for-free-on-frama.io)
> - 10GB transfer per month [2](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/)
> - 400 CI/CD minutes per month [3]
> - 5 users per namespace

Source: [Gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/)

Am I missing something?

Comment: They want your CC, which I do not like